# Obtain active status of Bootstrap buttons and submit as part of form php

Tags: php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using several buttons on my page of the same class. Here is an example:

```
<button id="YES" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" data-toggle="button" name="yesPowerwash">YES</button>
```

I believe I can determine whether or not the button has been toggled with the following (please correct me if I am wrong):

```
 $('[name="noPowerwash"]').hasClass('active')
```

I cannot figure out how to post the state (active vs inactive) as part of the form submission.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you are just trying to post if the button is clicked or not like a check box?

Comment: @Jay - I am just trying to submit the states of the buttons with the entire form.  I have about a dozen buttons and I need to read them all on the server side (i.e. true / false).

Comment: Thought I would bump this post just to see if anyone knows how to read the states of the buttons and send them to the server on form submit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just part of the value field in bootstrap.
i.e This is an example for a radio button you can change it to a regular button by just looking at the documentation [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons).

```
 <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" id="buycheckbox" value="buy" name="radiogroup" required>Buy
 </label>
```

So the value here is `buy`. Where ever you post too, let's say another php page you can check to see if the radiogroup button was clicked as buy. i.e

```
if($_POST['radiogroup'] == 'buy')
```

Your html:

```
  <form id="contact-form" method="POST" action="form-handling.php">
              <div class="success"> Contact form submitted! <strong>We will be in touch soon.</strong> </div>
              <fieldset>
            <div>
                <label class="name">
                <input type="text" value="name">
                <br>
                <span class="error">*This is not a valid name.</span> <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span> </label>
                </div>
            <div>
                <label class="phone">
                <input type="tel" value="Telephone">
                <br>
                <span class="error">*This is not a valid phone number.</span> <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span> </label>
                </div>
            <div>
                <label class="email">
                <input type="email" value="Email">
                <br>
                <span class="error">*This is not a valid email address.</span> <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span> </label>
                </div>
            <div>
                <label class="message">
                <textarea>Message</textarea>
                <br>
                <span class="error">*The message is too short.</span> <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span> </label>
                </div>
            <div class="buttons-wrapper"> <a class="btn btn-1" data-type="reset">Clear</a> <a class="btn btn-1" data-type="submit">Send</a></div>
          </fieldset>
            </form>
```

form-handling.php

```
name  =$_POST['name'];
tele = $_POST['Telephone']
..... etc
```

Now just add the button label/input to the form

Try this to do the toggleing its just another example.

It doesn't matter if the type = radio or check box its the div that gives the look.

```
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input name="year" value="2011" type="radio">2011
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input name="year" value="2012" type="radio">2012
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input name="year" value="2013" checked="" type="radio">2013
        </label>
  </div>
```

Comment: thanks for the response!  So it looks like the start of an IF statement so would it be if($_POST['radiogroup'] == 'buy') then $var='foobar'?

Comment: Um I don't really know what you are asking, could you explain it a litte more. But keep in mind that $_POST only works when the `<form method='POST' >` as a little heads up.  ALSO if my post helps be sure to click the check mark under the up down arrow next to my post.

Comment: I guess I was asking how that code works.  I would normally assign a form field to a variable like this: $variable=$_POST['fieldname']);  I gather from what you wrote that I could do this $variable=if($_POST['radiogroup'] == 'buy') so that buy is assigned to $variable - is that right?

Comment: Also, I tried to give you an up but I am sorry to report that it requires a reputation of at least 15 and this is my first post.  Sorry about that - I tried.

Comment: The check mark not the arrow up. And I'll update the post to show you an example to a form

Comment: Thanks, but I have it working for all text fields. I already do what you did: tele = $_POST['Telephone'].  The problem is that the button I created in Bootstrap is a toggle button.  It has a state of active or inactive.  For whatever reason PHP does not recognize this: someVar = $_POST['buttonname'].  I assume I either need to use Jquery to read the state and pass it on for submission or do something different.  I thought in your original post I could use this on the server side: if($_POST['radiogroup'] == 'buy') so I tried $someVar=if($_POST['yesPowerwash'] == 'yes').  It could not parse that

Comment: Oh I get your old post now. $variable=if($_POST['radiogroup'] == 'buy') should be assigned to $varaible yes

Comment: That is where I get the parse error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF in C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\xamppPacebands\XAMPP\xampp\htdocs\xampp\cook.php on line 7.  The code was: $yesPowerwash=if($_POST['yesPowerwash']=="yes"]);

Comment: Are you sure you are posting the button? Is it in the `<input >` tags?

Comment: I am not.  I did not know I needed to do that.  I did it this way - how can I correct it?  <div class="btn-group">
     <button id="YES" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" data-toggle="button" name="yesPowerwash">YES</button>
     <button id="NO" type="button"  class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" data-toggle="button" name="noPowerwash">NO</button>
   </div>  
   <br>

Comment: <div class="btn-group">
     <button id="YES" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" data-toggle="button" name="yesPowerwash">YES</button>
     <button id="NO" type="button"  class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" data-toggle="button" name="noPowerwash">NO</button>
   </div>  
   <br>

Comment: `<div class="btn-group">
  ...
</div>` you can then put the input and type in the div
Look at the documentation I showed you in the post. It really helps

Comment: Sorry to be so helpless.  I tried with the name input in the class tag and this way: <div class="btn-group"><input>buttons</input></div> neither worked ... am I supposed to do somthing different?

Comment: <div class="btn-group"><input type = "checkbox" value="buy" name="yesPowerwash" >buttons</input></div>

Comment: That changes it from a toggle button to a checkbox.  I am trying to read the state of a button to see if it is active or not (toggled) and use that as the value to pass to the server.  I don't want to use a checkbox.

Comment: THAT WORKS!!!  YOU ARE GREAT - THANKS FOR HANGING IN THERE WITH ME.  I will switch out my buttons to this style and use them instead.

Comment: Good :D glad to hear it